# "CodeRejected" when trying to deploy INK smart contract using M1 pro

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I'm trying to deploy INK! 3.3.0 smart contract to my local substrate node and Im getting

> CodeRejected; Can't decode wasm code.

When I compile my code i get no errors and using the following command to compile and build the smart contract:

```
cargo +nightly-2022-08-15 contract build
```

**Note**:

- I was able to deploy the contract not long ago, i think its stopped work after I updated rustup nightly.
- I get no error from the substrate console

```
./target/release/node-template --dev -l error,debug
```

Rustc nightly version: rustc 1.67.0-nightly (b3bc6bf31 2022-11-24)

I'm using MacBook Pro M1 Pro chip (13.0.1 (22A400) version)

Comment: I think this may be the issue with new rustc https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1417, ink 3.3.0 can be build with nightly-2022-06-30 and older, if you want to use the latest rustc then use ink 3.4.0, the issue is fixed there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `--optimization-passes=0` to the contract build command will fix the issue (only a work-a-round until official fix)