# Unable to deploy INK 4.0 beta smart contract

Tags: ink, smart-contract, cargo-contract

I'm trying to deploy INK 4.0 smart contract with cargo-contract 2.0 beta to a network but I'm getting the following error `contracts.CodeRejected`.

Whenever i try to upload the contract to my local substrate node I'm getting the following error:
`StorageDepositLimitExhausted, More storage was created than allowed by the storage deposit limit.`

As mentioned, I'm using INK 4.0 beta and cargo-contracts 2.0 beta.
I've tried compiling the following ways:

- `cargo contract build --optimization-passes=0`
- `cargo contract build`

I'm using MacBook pro M1 pro chip using MacOs Ventura (13.0.1 (22A400))

Thank you very much :)

Comment: My system specification is same as yours and I just created fresh project by using `cargo-contracts 2.0 beta` and uploaded but haven't faced any issue. [there is same issue as yours `contracts.CodeRejected`](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/6131/coderejected-when-trying-to-deploy-ink-smart-contract-using-m1-pro) but it's on ink 3.3.0

Comment: Mind sharing your compile command?

Comment: `cargo  contract build`

Comment: i have same issue while deploying on the rococo

Answer (score 2):

The network I'm trying to deploy the contract to is not supporting `INK! 4.0 beta` yet.

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue deploying on a local `0.21.0` node. I got it to work by running node version `0.23.0` instead.